# How to remove ansi code from output piped to VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pipe, ansi-colors

As of [November 2017](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_19#_pipe-output-directly-into-vs-code) VSCode allow to pipe output directly to VSCode. I did tried with a few command until I got a bunch of ANSI codes which I'm not interested.

I'm running something like `yarn info babel-core | code` and getting this:

```
yarn info v0.24.6
{ name: [32m'babel-core'[39m,
  description: [32m'A placeholder package that bridges babel-core to @babel/core.'[39m,
  [32m'dist-tags'[39m: 
   { latest: [32m'6.26.0'[39m,
     old: [32m'5.8.38'[39m,
     next: [32m'7.0.0-beta.3'[39m,
     bridge: [32m'7.0.0-bridge.0'[39m },
```

I would like to that output without these ANSI codes.

Answer (score 2):

If you NodeJS then you can globally install [strip-ansi-cli](https://github.com/chalk/strip-ansi-cli) which provides you the command: `strip-ansi`. It does exactly that.

For your case, you may use it as follow:

```
yarn info babel-core | strip-ansi | code
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, plugins now exist, e.g. [ANSI Colors](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iliazeus.vscode-ansi&ssr=false#overview), that once installed enable you to select `ANSI text` as the file's "*language mode*." You can then use [VS Code's _Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)_ (`Ctl-Sft-P`) to preview the file (`ANSI Text: Open Preview`) with escape sequences respected, i.e. in color (and etc.)

Credit

> [Can I display a file with ANSI color escape sequences in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67651122/418950)

Comment: it helps to convert text in editor. The question was about output window which is read-only.