# Can I display a file with ANSI color escape sequences in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a process that writes a log file which includes ANSI color codes. When I view the file on the terminal with `cat`, the colors are rendered correctly. When I view it with `less`, by default I see codes like `ESC[32m` but I can use the `-R` switch to see the colors (e.g. less -R log.txt).

I would like to be able to view and even possibly edit the file in VSCode, with the colors displayed correctly. How can I do this?

Comment: I've found https://github.com/aziz/SublimeANSI that seems to do it for sublime, but nothing for VS Code

Comment: I don't need to edit, just view would be great.

Comment: I'd love to know if someone implemented this as well.

Comment: Upvote this issue:  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/38834

Comment: At present, Tobias Faller have realized this function by writing extensions.  → [Terminal Color and Style Highlighting for the Editor - Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tobias-Faller.vt100-syntax-highlighting)

Comment: This question IS ON TOPIC, per the third bullet point at the top of https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic namely `software tools commonly used by programmers`.

Comment: This question is being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406915/please-reopen-so-question-48339982-because-it-is-on-topic).

Comment: The solution is a plugin named "ANSI Colors".

Answer (score 70):

The [ANSI Colors](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iliazeus.vscode-ansi) extension exists since 2020/10/13:

[image]

### TL;DR

Once installed, you can use the preview button in the top right (just like for Markdown):

[image]

### Long Version

0. Install the [ANSI Colors](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iliazeus.vscode-ansi) extension.
1. Open your ANSI file.
2. Use the preview button, or their custom commands to open the ANSI color preview, just like in this screenshot: [image]

   - Press `F1` or `CTRL/Command + SHIFT + P` (to open the VSCode command interface).
   - Type "ansi" or "preview" to find the commands.
   - Select with Up/Down arrow keys.
   - Finally, hit enter.
   - NOTE: As you can see, the command interface also shows you `keyboard shortcuts`, if you prefer those.

More usage and configuration options are explained on [the extension page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iliazeus.vscode-ansi).

Comment: Until discovering this answer, I (wrongly) concluded the [ANSI Colors plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=iliazeus.vscode-ansi) did not work. Your step #2 had eluded me, `...custom commands to open the ANSI color preview.` I failed to (**carefully**) RTFM. Thank you!

Comment: this looks great - but I noticed that this only appears to work for `.ans` or `.ansi` extensions by default. You can open preview mode manually and that works. But it looks like you have this workingn by default for `.txt` extensions - how did you manage that? - I can't for a setting to add more extensions

Comment: @code_fodder I just open it manually. I'd rather shoot myself in the foot before I have VSCode bombard me with all kinds of unwanted previews. After all, most `txt` files are not `ANSI`.

Comment: But... if you really wanted to shoot yourself in the foot? : ) - In my case I want to associate `.log` files which, for my part almost always have ansi colours...

Comment: @code_fodder check the docs: https://github.com/iliazeus/vscode-ansi#custom-file-icon

Comment: that is for icons. @code_fodder and I want to enable for this extension only. Is that possible?

Comment: @Domi Is there a way to avoid having to trigger the preview to get the colors and the symbols removed?
Like someone mentioned above: if my log files always have ansi colours, I'd like to open them and see them correctly right away without having to open the preview every time.

Answer (score -1):

Note: on Windows, [Curly and colored underlines](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/1145) would *not* be supported on Windows.

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6193135/76248036-d50c3f00-6240-11ea-855b-37e8aec72014.png]

That should change with VSCode 1.71 (Aug. 2022) and [issue 156983](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/156983), resolved by [Upgrading to xterm.js v5 beta](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/156993).

And VSCode 1.72 (Sept. 2022) should come with [Support hyperlink ansi escapes in the integrated terminal (issue 39278)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/39278).
[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/170270/33316814-8b35c2d4-d435-11e7-8524-da4fa076e6fb.png].
It is in [VSCode Insiders today](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

Comment: This question is about `files`, not the terminal. But I guess, this is still quite useful information, albeit tangential 

Comment: @Domi Agreed. I saw an improvement of color support both in terminal (and in files) starting with VSCode 1.72 on Windows.