# Running Minitest in latest VScode - Ansi color codes are displayed

Tags: ruby, visual-studio-code, minitest

When I run a Ruby test (minitest) automatically in VSCode by doing "run by language", the tests run but the outputs "ansi color codes" are displayed, as-is, instead of resulting in colorized output.

Comment: This may be relevant: [Can I display a file with ANSI color escape sequences in Visual Studio Code?.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67651122/418950)

Answer (score 1):

The setting in vscode "code-runner" preference seems to affect this. For me, when "run in terminal" is ON, then the ansi color codes work correctly. When that setting was OFF the color codes didn't work correctly.