# Terraform plan/apply into a readable file?

Tags: terraform

Apologies if this may appear like a trivial question, but when I usually run terraform plan or terraform apply you get a dump at the end of information about what what resources will be created, changed or destroyed. This is great!

However, as you may notice, sometimes this output of resources exceeds the terminal buffer, so I can't see all the resources being changed.

So how would I dump this exact information into a readable file so that I can view everything that is going to be changed?

Disclaimer - it is not `terraform plan -out=tfplan`, as this creates an unreadable file.

Anyone have any suggestions here? I also tried stdout into a file, but this did not show the full dump of resources as I need it to.

Comment: Why not just redirect stdout into a file?

Comment: "but this did not show the full dump of resources as I need it to" Why not? That is very unusual behavior.

Comment: If you're using Linux/Mac OS. Juts pipe to `less`. `terraform plan | less`

Answer (score 38):

After running `plan` with output file, I use `show` command with `-no-color`, for example:

`terraform plan -out tf.plan`

`terraform show -no-color tf.plan > tfplan.txt`

Answer (score 20):

**Edit**: You can use terraform plan -out=/path/to/file

If you are on Linux or Mac, you can redirect output to a file.

`terraform plan -no-color > output.txt`

You can then use any reader like a cat or any other file viewer to read the file.

Note: This will work on Windows as well using the git terminal.

Answer (score 9):

Saving as a plain monochrome text file is good for the record,
but I like to keep the colours as its easier to read.

This will create a text file with ANSI control characters that can be displayed with `less -R` or in VS Code using the [ANSI Colors extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339982/can-i-display-a-file-with-ansi-color-escape-sequences-in-visual-studio-code).

```bash
terraform plan -out tf.plan
terraform show  tf.plan > tfplan.ansi
less -R tfplan.ansi
```

Answer (score 1):

`terraform plan -out tf.plan` doesn't save the plan in a human readable format.

There are a few options to get the Plan in a human readable file, you always need the `-no-color` flag to not have ANSI scape commands.

One way is `terraform plan -no-color > tf.plan` to redirect the output to a file. I use this in scripts, to not pollute the terminal.

But my favorite way is `terraform plan -no-color | tee tf.plan`. This way you get the plan in the terminal and *also* in the `tf.plan` file. Useful when updating the code and saving the changes incrementally in different files.

Answer (score 0):

For content like the resolved userdata, the `strings` command can pull this from the plan file.  This can be useful when debugging an unexpected user data modification.